# How to open emoji keyboard on Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-inputtype

I am using this code in my xml file to show the emoji icon.

```
 android:inputType="textShortMessage|textMultiLine"
```

I want to know if there is a way we can show the keyboard by default. Something like this if I click the smiley button on my app it opens the keyboard with smiley view open.

Comment: did u get any solution?

Comment: any solution for this?

Comment: I couldn't find any.